# Inline IF withou ?:

Tags: php, if-statement

Can I do:

```
if ($param3) {
    $id = $param3;
} elseif ($param2) {
    $id = $param2;
} else {
    $id = $param1;
}
```

In simple form like:

```
$id = $param3 || $param2 || $param1;
```

Without using ?:

Comment: Why in the world would you have such a strange requirement?

Comment: To avoid long list of if / else. Such a simple task should be possible inline.

Comment: Avoiding `?` will not avoid a long list.  It is the common shortcut for if / else.  Attempting some alternative to the common shortcut will obfuscate your code and make it harder to maintain.  Short code should never be a higher priority than maintainable code.

Comment: ($id=$param3) || ($id=$param2) || ($id=$param1) is still easy to understand and way shorter than if/else.

Answer (score 0):

```
$param3 = NULL;
$param2 = 1;
$param1 = NULL;

$id = $param3 || $param2 || $param1;

print($id);
```

Seems a bad control, tho, as it will ouput error if any $paramN is tested and is not defined.Try commenting out the $param3 line.

Comment: people use SO to answer quizz questions don't they?

Comment: Won't that cast `$id` to a boolean?

Comment: $id will become boolean instead value.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by 'simple form'. In PHP, there are basically 3 ways of doing If-else control structures:
- If-else, normal: but you can't use that
- Alternative syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php
- Ternary like '?:', but you can't use that

So, it seems your only option is Alternative syntax. Which is especially useful in templating. If that doesn't work for you, then the answer to your question is no, there are no more ways to do an "if-else".

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of avoid `?` by doing :

```
($id=$param3)||($id=$param2)||($id=$param1)
```